# Bash associative array increment value strange behavior

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array

I want to increment value in associative array in bash, but i found some strange behavior. If value is 0 then error code is 1, otherwise it's 0. Code snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A arr

key="create|server"

arr["$key"]=0

(('arr["$key"]'++))
echo "err_code: $?" # 1, WTF

(('arr["$key"]'++))
echo "err_code: $?" # 0
```

Do you know what causes this strange behavior?

Comment: Note that associative arrays have nothing to do with this. You'll be equally surprised by `x=0; ((x++)); echo $?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Post* increment. Your expression evaluates as 0 (*false*) and the return status is 1. Use *pre*-increment:

```
(( ++arr["$key"] ))
```

if you want to avoid this. The expression will evaluate as 1 (*true*) and the return status will be 0.

Comment: I agree with what you say here, but *why* does Bash convert the result to a "truth" value like this?  I mean it looks like the first value is 0 so why is $? equal to 1?

Comment: Because it is how arithmetic evaluation is specified. If the expression evaluates to zero it is considered as *false*, which, in bash, corresponds to a non-zero return or exit status.

Comment: You say zero is considered false, but `false` sets `$?` to 1 and `true` sets it to 0.

Comment: @JohnZwinck `(())` evaluates 0 as false and passes a return code of 1 to bash. Any non zero number will evaluate as true and return a 0 to bash. Note they are two separate processes and have their own way of interpreting true or false.

Comment: @123: Thanks for the explanation.  I'm glad I stopped using Bash for scripting years ago.

Comment: @JohnZwinck It's not bash, it's how unix exit values work. An exit value of 0 indicates success, and hence is (sort of) considered true. A nonzero exit value indicates an error (with the specific value sometimes indicating what the error was), and hence is considered false. This is the opposite of the C convention, which makes it confusing; but in this specific context -- success/failure of processes -- it makes more sense. Unfortunately, bash arithmetic contexts use the C convention...

Comment: I would say, rather, that arithmetic contexts are the only things that bridge the divide between "expected" boolean values and the shell's fundamental distinction between success and failure. An arithmetic statement either succeeds or fails, like any other command, and it succeeds (by definition) when its expression has a non-zero value (i.e., a value conventionally held to be "true").

Comment: @GordonDavisson: I understand what you're saying.  I understand perfectly well how *nix exit codes work, and am comfortable with it.  But as you mention, Bash here has chosen to ignore its own conventions and implement this particular feature using opposite symbology.  Saying "It's not Bash" and then seemingly blaming it on C (which language is used nowhere in the question) is confusing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

From 'man bash'

```
((expression))
          The expression is evaluated according to  the  rules  described  below
          under  ARITHMETIC  EVALUATION.  If the value of the expression is non-
          zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1.   This
          is exactly equivalent to let "expression".
```